# Sum until a condition match

Tags: google-sheets

For the table below, I have a **tree-like structure**

[image]

I want to formulate the *hours (M) column* to **sum the leaf-tasks' hours within every group (Group 1 contains 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, and so on)**.

For example, M2 should be 60.50 
M5 should be 15.50 
M7 should be 16 
and thus M4 should be 31.50

How do I achieve this?

I've tried some approaches, but I'm stuck at being so unfamiliar with the formulas.
My current idea is to **sum all the leaf-tasks' hours below until encounters a row whose level number is less than or equal to us (out of the group)**.

Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression matching to find out all the leaf nodes under a given node. At a first approximation, make another column and fill it with formulas like so:
[image]
(the formula from C1 needs to be copied down along the C column in this example; I'm not sure if it possible to use a double arrayformula or perhaps a MMULT here, this is the first workable solution that came to me)